# FILEMAKER || Order "Months" Result in script

Tags: sorting, charts, filemaker

I got this script (Part of...).
It's meant to get a "Months list" to use in a Chart. But, it is or should be based on a fiscal year period (3 last months of 2017 and 9 months of 2018), So, Should be `October, November, December, January, February, ... August, September,`

The problem is I'm getting the result in a logical order I think:

```
January (2018), February (2018) ... September (2018), October (2017), November (2017), December (2017)
```

This is the part of the script:

```
Let     (
[
year = Invoices::Year ; 
decimal = Left ( Evaluate ( 1/2 ) ; 1 ) ; 
SQL = ExecuteSQL    ( 
                "
                SELECT a.\"Month\", a.\"Month Name\", SUM(a.\"Total_Consolidado\")
                FROM \"Invoices\" a
                WHERE a.\"Year\" = ?
                GROUP BY a.\"Month\", a.\"Month Name\"
                "
                ; "|" ; ¶  ; 
                year 
                )
] ; 
Substitute ( SQL ; "." ; decimal )
)
```

How could I manage to get the month list sorted by Date or Year, so it shows properly in a chart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the Month field is a number field, this is expected behavior. You need to include the year in the sort. Make a calculation field with the year first, followed by the month and order by that.

```
Year & Right(“0” & Month;2)
```

Comment: Just add ORDER BY and your calc field to your SQL statement

Comment: Just Perfect! Thanks AndreasT!